# Fullscreen not working on Firefox 30

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

When I am invoking fullscreen mode on Firefox 30 I am getting this error message on Firefox's console -

```
Request for full-screen was denied because Element.mozRequestFullScreen() was not called from       inside a short running user-generated event handler. jquery.fullscreen.js:182
```

Everything working fine on Chrome.
I am using this approach for fullscreen : https://github.com/private-face/jquery.fullscreen

Comment: I have put an answer as I suppose you did not follow the requirements to call the fullscreen method. But please put some code to give some context so we can give you better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an javascript confirm dialogue box in between the click of fullscreen button and $.fullscreen() in js side,

Solved the problem by **skipping js alert** on Firefox browsers.. Still thinking why it works fine on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably asked the browser to go on fullscreen directly from the code. It can only happen in an eventHandler called from an user action (like a click or keypress).This is what the user message is telling. As you can see, the eventHandler must run fast too. It must be under 1s.

It is for security reasons, so you cannot go fullscreen without requiring the user for confirmation.

Please see the [note at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode#When_a_fullscreen_request_fails) or the [W3C specification](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/fullscreen/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#security-and-privacy-considerations).